# Accessing research databases with company computer?

Tags: databases

Are there any legal (or other) limitations in accessing research databases from a computer at my workplace?

As a part-time student I have full access to resources provided by my university and was wondering whether I should stop using company's laptop for research purposes.

I'm based in UK, if that matters.

Comment: can you explain your situation exactly? You work at company X, go to Uni Y as what? and what did your manager say?

Comment: Can you clarify the nature of these research databases? I originally read your question to be about library resources but maybe you are talking about access to other types of data. In particular if these data are privileged then access from outside may be much worse than I've suggested so far in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should check with your library policies, but use of academic library (and other) resources *for work outside an academic educational/research context* is very likely against policy and may violate the licenses by which the university has obtained access to material (i.e., the library has obtained a license for the students and staff of the university to access the material for noncommercial purposes related to academic research and education; they likely have not obtained a license for those students and staff to access the material for commercial purposes outside the university).

Using your company's laptop might be a bit of a grey area since you are transferring materials to the property owned by the company; if you are using the company laptop for academic purposes, you might be in violation of company policies but it has nothing to do with the library access. Whether simply accessing library materials from a commercial source if you are not using those resources to do non-licensed work (i.e., to use the access for commercial purposes) seems like a question only a lawyer could answer, and you won't get legal advice here.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't understand how the first paragraph relates to the actual question.

Comment: @Buffy Mostly just setting up the background of why policies might prohibit the use: because the library doesn't give you permission and likely does not have permission themselves to share the material with a commercial entity. I think the OP understands this but I wanted to spell it out in my own words.

Comment: Still don't see it. The OP doesn't mention the Library. Neither does s/he suggest sharing with the company. I read it as using the laptop owned by the company.

Comment: @Buffy Hmm, when the OP says "research databases" I was presuming they were referring to library databases, but I suppose that may not be the case. I'll wait for clarification and edit; if these are other types of data it could be potentially even worse to access them this way. Thank you. I read it as the issue would be that using the company laptop could constitute sharing the resources with the company (whether or not they are actually used for company purposes).

Answer (score 0):

If a university has given you permission to access resources online, then the university will generally not care what machine you use to access them or what location you access them from.

It is possible that your company might have some policy about using your laptop only for company purposes, but that is a question for your supervisor and/or the IT staff at your company.  Most companies that I know of, however, would not have an issue with you accessing such material as long as you aren't doing it instead of the work the company has assigned you.